# Join multiple JSON objects into an array

Tags: json, jq

I have a command that outputs multiple simple json objects like this (for development purposes previously piped to a file `foo.txt`):

```
$ cat foo.txt
{"a": "b"}
{"a": "e"}
{"a": "f"}
```

Now I would like to get it formatted like this:

```
{
  "a": ["b", "e", "f"]
}
```

I am pretty sure it can be done with `jq`, but all I can get is the following:

```
$ cat foo.txt |jq -n '.a |= [inputs]'
{
  "a": [
    {
      "a": "b"
    },
    {
      "a": "e"
    },
    {
      "a": "f"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Is `.a` constant or it could change/dynamic ?

Comment: `a` is constant, not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close. JQ won't extract `.a` from input objects unless you explicitly state that.

```
$ jq -n '.a = [inputs.a]' foo.txt
{
  "a": [
    "b",
    "e",
    "f"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `inputs.a` won't work if I'm not mistaken, `inputs` is an array and you can't access its properties. `[inputs | map(.a)]` would work just fine though

Comment: @Aaron it's not. `inputs` is a stream, OP just forgot `.a`.

Comment: My bad, I had tested from my own sample and left the `--slurp`, which made `inputs` empty and raised an error that could be interpreted as trying to index an array with a field

Comment: np, I wouldn't have assumed so.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following :

```
jq --slurp --compact-output '{ a: map(.a) }' foo.txt
```

`--slurp` makes `jq` read a sequence of JSON objects as an array of those objects. We map this array of objects to an array of the values of their `.a` field, and finally return an object which holds this array as its `.a` field.

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/sFwfKCpIir).

Comment: The -s option is a relic of the days of yore when jq did not have `input` and `inputs`. When the goal is to illustrate or encourage best practices, its use should generally be avoided when possible except to highlight its inefficiency.

Comment: @peak thanks for your feedback, I felt using slurp mode made for simpler code and I wasn't aware of its inefficiency. I guess I'll have to get used to input[s]